# Connect to socket.io dynamically

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to connect the browser to my application via socket.io.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
</script>
```

With this standard method all works fine.
Now I'm trying to transform this connection in "dynamic" based on the IP of the server, something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        var socket;
        function loadFile(filename){
            var ip_server = location.host;
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0],
                fileref = document.createElement('script');
            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src", "http://"+ip_server+"/"+filename);
            body.appendChild( fileref ); 
        }
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            loadFile("socket.io/socket.io.js");
            socket = io.connect('http://'+location.host);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But firebug says ***ReferenceError: io is not defined*** on line `socket = io.connect('http://'+location.host);`.

How can I solve? There's a simple way to do what I'm thinking? 
Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  I sort of understand what you're doing, but not why you're doing it.

Comment: The application should work either in local or in LAN or over the internet.
If the link point to localhost when I try to connect from another computer the application will not start...Am I wrong?

Comment: You're a little wrong, but in a good way.  :)  See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Socket.io has "magical" integration with Node.js which means that something much simpler will work automatically:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect();
```

This will find the library and the socket with no explicit host or path.  It should "just work."

Comment: Magical ha ha ha.

Answer (score -1):

```
const socket = io.connect(location.href);
```