# Stuck on socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

So, I got node and downloaded the files, so I now have socket.io.js.

1. How do I use it in my project? Just like a normal JavaScript file?
2. What kind of address am I supposed to enter when I try to connect, I'm editing locally (localhost), but what about when I move it to my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to the first question:**

Did you use [npm, node.js package manager](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/README.html)? In case you didn't, I would highly recommend it. When using npm you don't need to manually copy individual files to your project.

[How to install npm](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) depends on you operating system.

After installation of npm you can run following command in you project folder to install [socket.io package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io).

```
npm install socket.io
```

On the [socket.io npm package page](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io) is brief get started code snippet that got me started with it on server:

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});

server.listen(3000);
```

[Source from socket.io package.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io)

Now your server socket is at location:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

On client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

[Source from socket.io home page.](http://socket.io/)

**Answer to the second question:**

What kind of address am I supposed to enter when I try to connect, I'm editing locally (localhost), but what about when I move it to my server?

You could on client side use for host and port following url:

```
// You might need to add the port of socket connection to the url. 
// :3000 in this case
var socket = io.connect(location.host);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think - as long as it's not cross domain - you don't even have to pass the host name.
So calling the `connect()` method without any arguments should work.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948558/1468708